# What is the standard for encoding a date as a timestamp?

Tags: date, datetime, timezone, momentjs, datetimepicker

Is there a standard for encoding a date as a timestamp? My thoughts:

1. This should be **12:00pm UTC in local time**, eg 9:00am at T-3, therefore anyone consuming the timestamp, regardless of their -12/+12 offset, will recognize the same date, regardless of whether they parse at the UTC timezone
2. It could be **12:00pm at UTC**
3. It could be the **start of the day** (12:00am) at UTC
4. It could be **start of the day** (12:00am UTC) in local time eg 9:00pm at T-3

---

Is there an official spec or standard to adhere to?

It would be easy to point to this document and say 'this is the standard' as opposed to being unaware and having to change our logic down the line.

Comment: Note that current time zones extend to UTC +14:00 to UTC -11:00 — see [Time Zone Map](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/).  You should still allow for UTC -12:00 in any design.  (See also Wikipedia [List of UTC time offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets).) . One consequence of this is that for a given date, such as 2019-01-01, there will be a period of ~50 hours while some region is calling the current time on that date (from 2019-01-01 00:00:00 +14:00 through 2019-01-01 23:59:59 -12:00).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a standard for this, because a date and a timestamp are logically two very different concepts.

- A date covers the entire range of time on that day, not a specific point in time.
- It may be a different date for a person in another time zone at any given point in time, but dates *themselves* do not have any association with time zones.  Visualize a date as just a square on a calendar, not a point on a timeline.
- Many APIs will use midnight (`00:00`) as the default time when a date-only value is assigned to a date+time value.  However:

  - Whether it is UTC based or local-time based is very dependent on that particular API.  There is no standard for this, nor is one answer necessarily better than the other.
  - Assigning a local-time midnight *can* be problematic for time zones with transitions near midnight.  For example, [in Santiago, Chile on 2019-09-08](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/chile/santiago?year=2019), the day started at `01:00` due to the start of DST.  There was no `00:00` on that day.

Also, you tagged your question with `momentjs`.  Since a `Moment` object is basically a timestamp (not a date), then Moment.js will generally assign the start of the day if provided a date-only value.  The time zone involved is key to deciding which moment that actually is, which illustrates my prior points.

For example:

```js
// Parsing as UTC
moment.utc('2019-09-08').format() //=> "2019-09-08T00:00:00Z"

// Parsing as Local Time (my local time zone is US Pacific Time)
moment('2019-09-08').format() //=> "2019-09-08T00:00:00-07:00"

// Parsing in a specific time zone (on a day without midnight)
moment.tz('2019-09-08', 'America/Santiago').format() //=> "2019-09-08T01:00:00-03:00"
```

Also keep in mind that sometimes APIs can be misnamed.  The JavaScript `Date` object is not a date-only value, but actually a timestamp, just like a moment.